# Debugger only hits breakpoint in second await call to method in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I have the following dart code in the latest Dart dev release (SDK  1.9.0-dev.8.0):

```dart
main() async  {
 var i = await testMethod(1);
 var j = await testMethod(2);
 var k = await testMethod(3);
}

int testMethod (int x) {
  var breakpoint = 'breakpoint is set here';
  print(x);
  return(x);
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in the first statement of the testmethod, the breakpoint only gets hit for the second call and third call, never for the first call. The console prints 1, then the debugger stops in at the breakpoint for the second call.

Is this still a bug in the async/await debugging or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's very probable a bug. They are still working on some issues related to async/await. What Dart version are you using?

Comment: Probably worth creating an issue when you have such an nice example to reproduce the issue (http://dartbug.com)

Comment: Just did. Thanks. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22447